# Pipeline input to out-file

Tags: powershell

I was trying to process a list of files and write them out to new places. For each file I'm making a new PS object with a file name and the new content. Then I want to write a file with the saved filename and the modified content.
This does not work:

```
$ci | % { new-object -typename psobject -property @{out=(get-content  $_ | % { if ($_ -match '^[0-9].* [AB]: (.*)$') { $matches[1] } } |% { $_ -replace '(\.|\?|,|!)',''  } );
name=$_.Name} | 
Out-File -PSPath ("e:\training\deu\$($_.Name)") -InputObject $_.out }
The property 'out' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
At line:1 char:418
+ ... training\deu\$($_.Name)") -InputObject $_.out }
+                    ~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict
```

However the following does work:

```
$all = $ci | % { new-object -typename psobject -property @{out=(get-content  $_ | % { if ($_ -match '^[0-9].* [AB]: (.*)$') { $matches[1] } } |% { $_ -replace '(\.|\?|,|!)','' } );
name=$_.Name}  }
$all | % {out-file -PSPath ("e:\training\deu\$($_.Name)") -InputObject $_.out}
```

what's the difference between the two? Clearly the property out does exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Out-File` doesn't expand piped lists into the `$_` variable.  Only certain cmdlets do that, like `Foreach-Object` and `Where-Object` (and more generally, any cmdlet that follows the Begin, Process, End workflow)

In the second case, your use of `$_.out` is inside a scriptblock which is passed to a `Foreach-Object`.  Foreach performs some magic, in which it iterates over the piped array, sets `$_` to the array element, and calls your scriptblock.

`Out-File` does not do any of that.  In your first code, the value of `$_` is an element of `$ci`, and was set by the outermost foreach.  That object doesn't contain an `out` member, hence the error.

Comment: but in the first case I'm also inside a for-each block, just not the first element in it. You can see the last brace after $_.out closes the for-each that started right after $ci

Comment: The only foreach your `Out-File` is inside is `$ci | % { ... }`. That means that `$_` is one of the elements of `$ci`, and not one of your carefully crafted PSObjects.  Unless `$ci` is a list of objects that have a `.out` member, `$_.out` will fail.